# Angular - Keep Mat Expansion Panel Expanded

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 6 `mat-expansion-panel` within a `mat-accordion`. The `mat-expansion-panel` is data bound to an array of `moves` as follows:

```
  <mat-accordion fxFlex
             displayMode="default"
             multi="false"
             style="overflow-y: auto; background-color: transparent;">
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let move of moves"
                     (opened)="onMoveOpened(move)">

  <mat-expansion-panel-header style="padding-left: 8px; height: 48px;" expandedHeight="48px">

        <move-header [move]="move" style="width: 100%; padding: 0;"
                     (moveSelected)="onMoveSelected(move)">

        </move-header>

  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <move-info [move]="move" style="width: 100%;"></move-info>


  <mat-action-row style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
    <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="onClickEdit(move)">Edit</button>

    <button mat-mini-fab
            color="accent"
            (click)="onClickClockwise($event, move)"
            style="transform: scale(0.6);">
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px;">redo</i>
    </button>
    <button mat-mini-fab
            color="accent"
            (click)="onClickAntiClockwise($event, move)"
            style="transform: scale(0.6);">
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; transform: scale(-1, 1);">redo</i>
    </button>

  </mat-action-row>

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

The `mat-action-row` has two buttons, clockwise and anticlockwise, which re-position some graphics on screen. The functions which calculate the new positions of the graphics update the values in the `moves` array, because the graphics are data bound to `moves` as well. The effect of this is to redraw the `mat-expansion-panel` which closes the opened panel which the user is using. If the user wants to click one of the buttons in the `mat-action-row` a few times, they have to open the panel each time, which is annoying!

I tried adding an `expanded` property to my `move` class and binding the `expanded` property of each panel to this. It helped, but after clicking a `mat-action-row` button, the `mat-expansion-panel` would redraw and the panel would partly close and then open again.

Any suggestions very welcome as to how I could keep the panel open until either it is manually closed, by clicking on the up arrow, or until another panel is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this piece of code and succeeded:

```
if(this.matExpansionPanel.extended) { // usually return false for it catched the state when you clicked the button - when the panel was still closed
    // do something you want
}
else {
    this.matExpansionPanel.toggle();
    // do something you want
}
```

In your case, inside the `mat-extension-panel` tag, add `#youNameIt='matExpansionPanel'`.

The `matExpansionPanel` is the exported type of angular material expansion panel, as mentioned in [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview).
Back to the `.ts` script, add `@ViewChild('youNameIt') matExpansionPanel /*or any name you want*/ : MatExpansionPanel`, then add the above script inside your on click function

Answer (score 0):

To avoid panel collapse on repaint, as well as some flickering even though it doesn't collapse on repaint, you need to keep track of what panels are open, and also use the `trackBy` on the `ngFor`. I did this:

```html
    <mat-accordion multi>
      <mat-expansion-panel
        *ngFor="let item of items$ | async; index as index; trackBy:trackById"
        (opened)="panelOpened(index)"
        (closed)="panelClosed(index)"
        [expanded]="isExpanded(index)">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            ...
```

and then on TS:

```
  panelOpenStateIndexes: Set<number> = new Set();


  trackById = (index: number, item: any) => item.id;

  panelOpened = (index: number) => this.panelOpenStateIndexes.add(index);

  panelClosed = (index: number) => this.panelOpenStateIndexes.delete(index);

  isExpanded = (index: number) => this.panelOpenStateIndexes.has(index);
```

In my case this works because my array of items won't allow items to change position. Nevertheless, I was experiencing the same problem as you did because they repainted when changing status and content on both, header and inside the panel.

You can of course adapt to use your id instead of the index, like:

```html
(opened)="panelOpened(index, item)"
```

and:

```
panelOpened = (index: number, item: any) => this.panelOpenStateIndexes.add(item.id);
```